# select backward associated in django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm wrinting a Django project.

In `courses/models.py`

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Language(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to get list of all `Category` and then loop through each `Language` of specified category.

```
class Courses(ListView):
    template_name = 'courses/index.html'
    model = Course
    context_object_name = 'courses'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Courses, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        context['categories'] = categories
        return context
```

in template `courses/index.html` I want to show the list of languages based on category

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {{ category.title }}
    <li>lis of languages in this category</li>
{% endfor %}
```

**How to loop on backward associated data?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django creates a relation that is accessible in the templates through the `modelname_set` key.

In your case, you'd have to iterate over:
`category.language_set.all`

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {{ category.title }}
    {% for language in category.language_set.all %}
        <li>{{ language.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

_set does this work.
eg. in your case this code must work:

{% for language in category.language_set.all %}

{{ language.title }}

{% endfor %}